# Dynamic C# Curve with PointF in WinForm

Tags: c#

I need to make a WinForm that will draw a curve. I have an array with doubles in pairs simulating values coming from an external source and I need to pass them to the PointF array to be able to draw the curve or line. When I add the value to the PointF array I  am getting the error Cannot implicitly convert type **'System.Drawing.PointF' to 'System.Drawing.PointF[]'**

My code is as below.

```
    PointF[] toFloats;
    double [,] measureing_points = {
       { 61.5, 49.8 },
       { 5.2, 2.8 },
       { 4.1, 4.4 },
       { 1.6, 1.6 },
       { 3.1, 1.5 },
       { 6.8, 2 },
       { 7.5, 4.5 },
       { 8, 8.8 },
       { 9, 11 },
       { 11.5, 12 },
       { 13.2, 10.8 },
       { 11, 8 },
       { 9.8, 9.2 },
       { 12, 11 },
       { 50, 32 }
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < measureing_points.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        float x = (float)measureing_points[i, 0];
        float y = (float)measureing_points[i, 0];
        toFloats = new PointF(x, y);
        
    }
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
    e.Graphics.DrawCurve(pen, toFloats);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Typo: change `float y = (float)measureing_points[i, 0];` to `float y = (float)measureing_points[i, 1];`

Comment: Typo: change: `measureing_points` to `measuring_points`

Comment: Typo: change: `measureing_points.Length` to `measureing_points.GetLength(0)` as in `for (int i = 0; i < measureing_points.GetLength(0); i++)`

Comment: Thank you everyone for the different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toFloats` is a `PointF[]` but you try to assign a single `PointF` to it.
You need to create the array before adding items to it. Since you know how many items you'll create you don't need a `List` (for the dynamic size).

```
double [,] measureing_points = {
    { 61.5, 49.8 },
    { 5.2, 2.8 },
    { 4.1, 4.4 },
    { 1.6, 1.6 },
    { 3.1, 1.5 },
    { 6.8, 2 },
    { 7.5, 4.5 },
    { 8, 8.8 },
    { 9, 11 },
    { 11.5, 12 },
    { 13.2, 10.8 },
    { 11, 8 },
    { 9.8, 9.2 },
    { 12, 11 },
    { 50, 32 }
};
    
int size = measureing_points.Length / 2;
PointF[] toFloats = new PointF[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    float x = (float)measureing_points[i, 0];
    float y = (float)measureing_points[i, 0]; // shouldn't this be [i, 1]?
    toFloats[i] = new PointF(x, y);
}

Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
e.Graphics.DrawCurve(pen, toFloats);
```

Comment: Sorry yes, it is supposed to be [i, 1]

Answer (score 0):

The `toFloats` was define as `PointF[]` that means this variable is an array but you assign a `new PointF(x,y)` into it, `new PointF(x,y)` return an object not an array. perhaps you can try this follow code:

```
PointF[] toFloats;
    double [,] measureing_points = {
       { 61.5, 49.8 },
       { 5.2, 2.8 },
       { 4.1, 4.4 },
       { 1.6, 1.6 },
       { 3.1, 1.5 },
       { 6.8, 2 },
       { 7.5, 4.5 },
       { 8, 8.8 },
       { 9, 11 },
       { 11.5, 12 },
       { 13.2, 10.8 },
       { 11, 8 },
       { 9.8, 9.2 },
       { 12, 11 },
       { 50, 32 }
    };
    List<PointF> tempList = new List<PointF>(); // we hypothesis we doesn't know how many items in data-source
    for (int i = 0; i < measureing_points.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        float x = (float)measureing_points[i, 0];
        float y = (float)measureing_points[i, 0];
        tempList.Add(new PointF(x, y));
        
    }
    toFloats = tempList.ToArray(); // parse all 'measureing_points' to array
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
    e.Graphics.DrawCurve(pen, toFloats);
```

Answer (score 0):

For future proof, I often re-use a library to draw on winforms using `double` based coordinates and some scaling factor.

The following example is fairly easy to achieve

[image: scr1]

with driving code in the form's `OnPaint()` event

#### Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        double[,] measuring_points = {
                   { 61.5, 49.8 },
                   { 5.2, 2.8 },
                   { 4.1, 4.4 },
                   { 1.6, 1.6 },
                   { 3.1, 1.5 },
                   { 6.8, 2 },
                   { 7.5, 4.5 },
                   { 8, 8.8 },
                   { 9, 11 },
                   { 11.5, 12 },
                   { 13.2, 10.8 },
                   { 11, 8 },
                   { 9.8, 9.2 },
                   { 12, 11 },
                   { 50, 32 } };

        float scale = 5f;
        float originPixelX = ClientSize.Width / 4, originPixelY = ClientSize.Height - ClientSize.Height / 4;

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(originPixelX, originPixelY);

        // Draw coordinate axes for reference
        Gdi.DrawAxes(e.Graphics, scale, size: 50f);

        // Draw a curve through the points
        Gdi.Stroke.AddEndArrow(5f);
        Gdi.Stroke.Color = Color.Blue;
        Gdi.DrawCurve(e.Graphics, scale, measuring_points);
        Gdi.Stroke.RemoveEndArrow();
        
        // Draw little circles on the points
        Gdi.Stroke.Color = Color.Blue;
        Gdi.DrawPoints(e.Graphics, scale, measuring_points);

        // Draw labels next to the points
        for (int i = 0; i < measuring_points.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Gdi.DrawText(e.Graphics, scale, $"{(char)('A' + i)}", 
                measuring_points[i, 0], measuring_points[i, 1], 
                ContentAlignment.BottomRight);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the drawing of the curve is done with the following method `DrawCurve()` inside the `Gdi` class (see appendix) that calls the `Graphics.DrawCurve()` method with `PointF` structures.

```
public static void DrawCurve(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes)
{
    if (nodes.GetLength(0) <= 1) return;
    PointF[] points = new PointF[nodes.GetLength(0)];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        points[i] = new PointF(scale * (float)nodes[i,0], -scale * (float)nodes[i,1]);
    }
    g.DrawCurve(Stroke, points);
}
```

---

### Appendix I

The contents of the library are

#### Gdi.cs

```
public static class Gdi
{
    public static Pen Stroke { get; set; } = new Pen(Color.Black, 0);
    public static SolidBrush Fill { get; set; } = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    public static Font Font { get; set; } = SystemFonts.CaptionFont;

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an arrow to the start of a <see cref="Pen"/> object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Intended to be used with <see cref="Stroke"/></remarks>
    /// <param name="pen">The pen to modify.</param>
    /// <param name="arrowSize">Size of the arrow in pixels.</param>
    public static void AddStartArrow(this Pen pen, float arrowSize)
    {
        pen.CustomStartCap = new AdjustableArrowCap(arrowSize/2, arrowSize);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the start arrow from a <see cref="Pen"/> object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Intended to be used with <see cref="Stroke"/></remarks>
    /// <param name="pen">The pen object to modify.</param>
    public static void RemoveStartArrow(this Pen pen)
    {
        pen.StartCap = LineCap.NoAnchor;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an arrow to the end of a <see cref="Pen"/> object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Intended to be used with <see cref="Stroke"/></remarks>
    /// <param name="pen">The pen to modify.</param>
    /// <param name="arrowSize">Size of the arrow in pixels.</param>
    public static void AddEndArrow(this Pen pen, float arrowSize)
    {
        pen.CustomEndCap = new AdjustableArrowCap(arrowSize/2, arrowSize);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the end arrow from a <see cref="Pen"/> object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Intended to be used with <see cref="Stroke"/></remarks>
    /// <param name="pen">The pen object to modify.</param>
    public static void RemoveEndArrow(this Pen pen)
    {
        pen.EndCap = LineCap.NoAnchor;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws two axis along the x and y directions using arrowed lines and a dot at the origin.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graphics">The graphics.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="size">The size of arrows and dot in pixels.</param>
    public static void DrawAxes(this Graphics graphics, float scale, float arrowSize=1f)
    {
        float arrowTip = Math.Max(scale/5, arrowSize/2);
        AddEndArrow(Stroke, arrowTip);
        DrawLine(graphics, scale, 0, 0, arrowSize, 0d);
        DrawLine(graphics, scale, 0, 0, 0d, arrowSize);
        FillPoint(graphics, scale, 0d, 0d, arrowTip);
        RemoveEndArrow(Stroke);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a small circle representing a point on the screen.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="point">The point location.</param>
    /// <param name="size">The size of the circle.</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw the shape.</remarks>
    public static void DrawPoint(this Graphics g, float scale, double pointX, double pointY, float size = 6f)
    {
        float x = scale * (float)pointX, y = -scale * (float)pointY;
        g.DrawEllipse(Stroke, x - size / 2, y - size / 2, size, size);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Fills a small circle representing a point on the screen.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="point">The point location.</param>
    /// <param name="size">The size of the circle.</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Fill"/> to fill the shape.</remarks>
    public static void FillPoint(this Graphics g, float scale, double pointX, double pointY, float size = 6f)
    {
        float x = scale * (float)pointX, y = -scale * (float)pointY;
        g.FillEllipse(Fill, x - size / 2, y - size / 2, size, size);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a set of points (nodes)
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>There must be more than one node to draw anything.</remarks>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="nodes">The array of locations defining the points</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw the shape.</remarks>
    public static void DrawPoints(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes, float size = 6)
    {
        PointF[] points = new PointF[nodes.GetLength(0)];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            DrawPoint(g, scale, nodes[i, 0], nodes[i, 1],size);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a set of points (nodes)
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>There must be more than one node to draw anything.</remarks>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="nodes">The array of locations defining the points</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw the shape.</remarks>
    public static void FillPoints(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes, float size = 6)
    {
        PointF[] points = new PointF[nodes.GetLength(0)];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            FillPoint(g, scale, nodes[i, 0], nodes[i, 1],size);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws consecutive lines defined by their end points (nodes)
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>There must be more than one node to draw anything.</remarks>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="nodes">The array of locations defining the nodes of the (consecutive) lines</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw the shape.</remarks>
    public static void DrawLines(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes)
    {
        if (nodes.GetLength(0) <= 1) return;
        PointF[] points = new PointF[nodes.GetLength(0)];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            points[i] = new PointF(scale * (float)nodes[i,0], -scale * (float)nodes[i,1]);
        }
        g.DrawLines(Stroke, points);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a curve through a set of points (nodes)
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>There must be more than one node to draw anything.</remarks>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="nodes">The array of locations defining the nodes of the (consecutive) lines</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw the shape.</remarks>
    public static void DrawCurve(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes)
    {
        if (nodes.GetLength(0) <= 1) return;
        PointF[] points = new PointF[nodes.GetLength(0)];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            points[i] = new PointF(scale * (float)nodes[i,0], -scale * (float)nodes[i,1]);
        }
        g.DrawCurve(Stroke, points);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a closed shape with lines defined by the end points (nodes).
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>There must be more than one node to draw anything.</remarks>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="nodes">The array of locations defining the nodes of the (consecutive) lines</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw the shape.</remarks>
    public static void DrawPolygon(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes)
    {
        if (nodes.GetLength(0) <= 1) return;
        PointF[] points = new PointF[nodes.GetLength(0)];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            points[i] = new PointF(scale * (float)nodes[i,0], -scale * (float)nodes[i,1]);
        }
        g.DrawPolygon(Stroke, points);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a closed curve through several points (nodes).
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>There must be more than one node to draw anything.</remarks>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="nodes">The array of locations defining the nodes of the (consecutive) lines</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw the shape.</remarks>
    public static void DrawClosedCurve(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes)
    {
        if (nodes.GetLength(0) <= 1) return;
        PointF[] points = new PointF[nodes.GetLength(0)];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            points[i] = new PointF(scale * (float)nodes[i,0], -scale * (float)nodes[i,1]);
        }
        g.DrawClosedCurve(Stroke, points);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Fills a closed shape with lines defined by the end points (nodes).
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>There must be more than one node to draw anything.</remarks>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="nodes">The array of locations defining the nodes of the (consecutive) lines</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Fill"/> to fill the shape.</remarks>
    public static void FillPolygon(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes)
    {
        if (nodes.GetLength(0) <= 1) return;
        PointF[] points = new PointF[nodes.GetLength(0)];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            points[i] = new PointF(scale * (float)nodes[i,0], -scale * (float)nodes[i,1]);
        }
        g.FillPolygon(Fill, points);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Fills a closed curve though several points (nodes).
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>There must be more than one node to draw anything.</remarks>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="nodes">The array of locations defining the nodes of the (consecutive) lines</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Fill"/> to fill the shape.</remarks>
    public static void FillClosedCurve(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes)
    {
        if (nodes.GetLength(0) <= 1) return;
        PointF[] points = new PointF[nodes.GetLength(0)];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            points[i] = new PointF(scale * (float)nodes[i,0], -scale * (float)nodes[i,1]);
        }
        g.FillClosedCurve(Fill, points);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draw a line between two points.
    /// </summary>        
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="fromPosition">The start position.</param>
    /// <param name="toPosition">The end position.</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw the shape.</remarks>
    public static void DrawLine(this Graphics g, float scale, double fromPositionX, double fromPositionY, double toPositionX, double toPositionY)
    {
        float x1 = scale * (float)fromPositionX, y1 = -scale * (float)fromPositionY;
        float x2 = scale * (float)toPositionX, y2 = -scale * (float)toPositionY;
        g.DrawLine(Stroke, x1 ,y1, x2, y2);            
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draw a line from a point, to a certain offset using pixel coordinates.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="fromPosition">The start position.</param>
    /// <param name="xPixelOffset">The horizontal offset.</param>
    /// <param name="yPixelOffset">The vertical offset.</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw the shape.</remarks>
    public static void DrawLine(this Graphics g, float scale, double fromPositionX, double fromPositionY, float xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset)
    {
        float x = scale * (float)fromPositionX, y = -scale * (float)fromPositionY;
        g.DrawLine(Stroke, x, y, xPixelOffset, -yPixelOffset);            
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws an ellipse
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="center">The center of the ellipse.</param>
    /// <param name="semiMajor">The semi-major axis.</param>
    /// <param name="semiMinor">The semi-minor axis.</param>
    /// <param name="tiltAngleDegrees">The tilt angle degrees CCW from horizontal.</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw lines.</remarks>
    public static void DrawEllipse(this Graphics g, float scale, double centerX, double centerY, float semiMajor, float semiMinor, float tiltAngleDegrees = 0)
    {
        float x = scale * (float)centerX, y = scale * (float)centerY;
        float dx = scale * semiMajor, dy = scale * semiMinor;
        var save = g.Save();
        g.RotateTransform(-tiltAngleDegrees);
        g.DrawEllipse(Stroke, x - dx, y - dy, 2 * dx, 2 * dy);            
        g.Restore(save);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Fills an ellipse
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="center">The center of the ellipse.</param>
    /// <param name="semiMajor">The semi-major axis.</param>
    /// <param name="semiMinor">The semi-minor axis.</param>
    /// <param name="tiltAngleDegrees">The tilt angle degrees CCW from horizontal.</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Fill"/> to fill shapes.</remarks>
    public static void FillEllipse(this Graphics g, float scale, double centerX, double centerY, float semiMajor, float semiMinor, float tiltAngleDegrees = 0)
    {
        float x = scale * (float)centerX, y = scale * (float)centerY;
        float dx = scale * semiMajor, dy = scale * semiMinor;
        var save = g.Save();
        g.RotateTransform(-tiltAngleDegrees);
        g.FillEllipse(Fill, x - dx, y - dy, 2 * dx, 2 * dy);            
        g.Restore(save);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws an arc of an ellipse (partial ellipse)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="center">The center of the ellipse.</param>
    /// <param name="semiMajor">The semi-major axis.</param>
    /// <param name="semiMinor">The semi-minor axis.</param>
    /// <param name="startAngleDegrees">The start angle in degrees CCW from 3 o'clock.</param>
    /// <param name="sweepAngleDegrees">The sweep angle in degrees CCW.</param>
    /// <param name="tiltAngleDegrees">The tilt angle degrees CCW from horizontal.</param>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw lines.</remarks>
    public static void DrawEllipseArc(this Graphics g, float scale, double centerX, double centerY, float semiMajor, float semiMinor, float startAngleDegrees, float sweepAngleDegrees, float tiltAngleDegrees = 0)
    {
        float x = scale * (float)centerX, y = scale * (float)centerY;
        float dx = scale * semiMajor, dy = scale * semiMinor;
        //float θ = 
        var save = g.Save();
        g.RotateTransform(-tiltAngleDegrees);
        g.DrawArc(Stroke, x - dx, y - dy, 2 * dx, 2 * dy, 360 - startAngleDegrees, -sweepAngleDegrees); 
        g.Restore(save);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws the text.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="g">The graphics object to draw on.</param>
    /// <param name="scale">The drawing scale converting (x, y) to <see cref="PointF"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="text">The text to draw.</param>
    /// <param name="anchor">The anchor point.</param>
    /// <param name="alignment">The alignment of the text relative to the anchor point.</param>
    /// <param name="padding">The padding in pixels to space from anchor point.</param>
    /// <exception cref="System.NotSupportedException">For invalid <paramref name="alignment"/>.</exception>
    /// <remarks>Uses <see cref="Stroke"/> to draw text.</remarks>
    public static void DrawText(this Graphics g, float scale, string text, double anchorX, double anchorY, ContentAlignment alignment, int padding=4)
    {
        SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, Font);
        float x = scale * (float)anchorX, y = -scale * (float)anchorY;
        switch (alignment)
        {
            case ContentAlignment.TopLeft:
                x = x - size.Width - padding;
                y = y - size.Height - padding;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.TopCenter:
                x = x - size.Width/2;
                y = y - size.Height - padding;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.TopRight:
                x = x + padding;
                y = y - size.Height - padding;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
                x = x - size.Width - padding;
                y = y - size.Height/2;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
                x = x - size.Width/2;
                y = y - size.Height/2;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                x = x + padding;
                y = y - size.Height/2;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
                x = x - size.Width - padding;
                y = y + padding;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
                x = x - size.Width/2;
                y = y + padding;
                break;
            case ContentAlignment.BottomRight:
                x = x + padding;
                y = y + padding;
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        g.DrawString(text, Font, Fill, x, y);
    }
}
```

which you are free to copy and paste into your own code to use over and over again.

The following properties are defined

- **`.Stroke`** - a `Pen` object used for drawing lines.
- **`.Fill`** - a `SolidBrush` object used for filling shapes.
- **`.Font`** - the `Font` object used to draw text.

and the following methods are defined to modify the properties

- **`AddStartArrow(this Pen pen, float arrowSize)`** - Adds an arrow on the end of lines drawn of a specific size in pixels
- **`RemoveStartArrow(this Pen pen)`** - Removes the arrow on the end of lines drawn
- **`AddEndArrow(this Pen pen, float arrowSize)`** - Adds an arrow on the beginning of lines drawn of a specific size in pixels
- **`RemoveEndArrow(this Pen pen)`** - Removes the arrow on the beginning of lines drawn

and the following relevant extension methods are defined as well as many more. You want to look into the code for `DrawCurve()` to specifically answer your question.

- **`DrawAxes(this Graphics graphics, float scale, double size=1d)`**
- **`DrawPoint(this Graphics g, float scale, double pointX, double pointY, float size = 6f)`**
- **`DrawLines(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes)`**
- **`DrawCurve(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes)`**
- **`DrawPolygon(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes)`**
- **`DrawClosedCurve(this Graphics g, float scale, double[,] nodes)`**

<sub>See XML documentation in code source for explanations.</sub>

- The source for [`Gdi.cs`](https://gist.github.com/ja72/8faac41da525c5750ee08c6fd15c04ef) file as gist.